# angular 2 : Using slick caroussel inside a template

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I use slick carousel as a component in my angular project ; this slick component is like below :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'slick-slider',

    template: `
        <ng-content></ng-content>`,
    styleUrls:['./slick.component.css']  
    })
export class SlickSliderComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @Input() options: [any];
    $element: any;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.$element = jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).slick(this.options);  }
 }
```

in the template of foodsComponent who use this slick component I have a menu of 7 tab list each one fetch different content:

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(1)"></li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(2)"></li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(3)"></li>
..
..</ul>
<slick-slider class="slick-slider" *ngIf="foods" > 

    <div class="item"  style="width: 450px;" *ngFor= "let food of foods">
    <div class="thumbnail-menu-modern" >  
..
..
</slick-slider>
```

Onload the page the slick work fine because I display the first menu cause of this function on foodsComponent `ngOnInit() {this.onGetFoodsByCategorie(1);}`
but when I click in any menu the slick dosnt work I find the reason why this is happening is because the plugin itself drastically modifies the html that is generated by the *ngfor leaving angular unable to update the repeater as it no longer can identify the structure.
How -.Uninitialize the plugin.
-.Update the repeater.
-.Reinitialize the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the slick-slider component I detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137285/slick-carousel-with-angular-2?noredirect=1#comment72994943_40137285) I think you'll need to modify it a little. I was reading the specs of the slider [here](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and you have methods to add/remove a slide. So maybe the workaround would be adding a new method to the slick-slider component to update the sliders. Something like this:

```
update(elements: any[]) {
    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).slickRemove() //for each slide you have
    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).slickAdd('...') //for each new slide with the required template
}
```

Haven't tested this, but I think this could be the way to go.